# How to Display date in Toast

Tags: android, date, toast

I dont know what is wrong with the below code the month it returns is less than one.

Eg: When I click 26/6/2016 it displays as 26/5/2016

```
calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
   @Override public void onSelectedDayChange(
      CalendarView view,
      int          year,
      int          month,
      int          dayOfMonth ) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ""+dayOfMonth+ " / " + month + " / " + year, 0).show();
   }
});
```

Comment: The months are zero-based. That is, add `1` to `month`.

Comment: As @MikeM. said its starts from 0 Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener.html

Comment: how can i change to 1

Comment: Plus 1 manually in month value i.e.`dayOfMonth+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

Month is a zero based value that means for January it 0 and so on. You have to add 1 in to month value.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dayOfMonth+ " / " + (month+1) + " / " + year, 0).show();
```

Comment: Then why did u add to dayofMonth?

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.MONTH returns month which is zero-based that is why it is giving 1 less than actual month Add 1 to get correct value.

```
String result = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
```

credits : @Manishika

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the Replies.This coding works i just initialized an variable for incrementing month

```
calendar=(CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    int mon=month+1;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dayOfMonth+ " / " + mon + " / " + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+dayOfMonth+ " / " + (month+1) + " / " + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: same O/P i m getting